# Django storage exists fails on non-ascii characters

Tags: python, django, django-storage

I have a static file with the name `Foo-Bar-BaröFoo.pdf` in the static folder. 
When I view the file in the browser with the name `/static/Foo-Bar-BaröFoo.pdf` it renders fine.

But here is a scenrio, where i need to look if that file is present/exists or not.
I am using django storage to check for that file.

```
path=u'Foo-Bar-BaröFoo.pdf'
storage.exists(path)
```

It fails.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 40: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What can be the solution for that? Maybe some encoding / decoding?

### Already tried

```
path = path.encode('utf-8')
```

**exception:**

```
SuspiciousFileOperation: Suspicio...8f3f6)',)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the following encoding identifier at the top of your script and you should save the file in UTF-8 format:

```
# coding=utf-8
```

If you are using Python 2.x, you must also use the `u` prefix:

```
path = u'Foo-Bar-BaröFoo.pdf'
```

[PEP-0263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) explains this in detail:

> To define a source code encoding, a magic comment must
>       be placed into the source files either as first or second
>       line in the file, such as:
>
> ```
> # coding=<encoding name>
> ```

Comment: by default when i get path from mongo, i get `path=u'/static/Foo-Bar-Bar\xf6Foo.pdf'` When i call `exists()` it fails. Not `\xf6` in path

Comment: it seems that `\xf6` is replacing with that special char/symbol in your file name like `Bar\xfsFoo`

Comment: @NiviD yes that true, and it errors out with `SuspiciousFileOperation`

Comment: can you check out when and where it is replacing ?